# React Native returns promise

Tags: react-native, ethereum, blockchain, web3js

I want to get balance of given address.

```
  var x =  web3.eth.getBalance("0x81b7E08F65Bdf5648606c89998A9CC8164397647")
      .then(function (balance) {
        console.log(balance.toString);
      }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
      });
      console.log(x);
```

It returns promise as a JSON

```
Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}
```

As per `web3.eth.getBalance()` function I should get balance of given address but I am getting promise as result

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try parsing the JSON to handle the promise like this:

```
var x =  web3.eth.getBalance("0x81b7E08F65Bdf5648606c89998A9CC8164397647")
.then(function (result) {
   return result.json();
}
.then(balance) {
    console.log(balance.toString);
}).catch(function(e) {
   console.log(e);
});
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to resolve a promise. You cannot just assign it to a variable like you are assigning it to `x`. You can either do it in the `.then()` or you can use `await`.